# Lie Algebra of $SL_n(\mathbb H)$

Tags: lie-algebras

The Lie algebra of $SL_n(\mathbb C)$ are the matrices where the trace is $0$. But what is the Lie algebra of $SL_n(\mathbb H)$ where $\mathbb H$ is the quaternions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The obvious canditate for $\mathfrak{sl}_2(H)$ is the space of $2\times 2$ matrices $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$ with quaternion entries such that $a+d=0$, with bracket the commutator of matrices, but... that is not a Lie algebra.

For example, the trace of the commutator of $\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}j&0\\0&-j\end{pmatrix}$ is not zero.

The big problem, really, is that you have to decide what you mean by $SL_2(H)$. There is no determinant... (There is the Dieudonné determinant, though)

Comment: I think the easiest way to define $SL_n(\mathbb H)$ is as the group generated by the upper and lower unitriangular matrices with entries in $\mathbb H$ (for $n=1$ one should throw in the multiplicative commutators, i.e., norm $1$ quaternions, I think). This should coincide with the definition by the Dieudonné determinant, and in any case produce a group of *real* codimension $1$ in $GL_n(\mathbb H)$.

Comment: See my answer for a slightly less obvious but obviously working approach via the derived subalgebra, with correct codimension $1$ as @MarcvanLeeuwen suggests.

Answer (score 2):

The group $\mathrm{SL}(n, \mathbb{H})$ is defined here:

- Wikipedia, [GL(n,H) and SL(n,H)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_group#GL(n,_H)_and_SL(n,_H)).

It works like this:

The algebra of quaternions is a subalgebra of the $2 \times 2$ complex matrices in a standard way. This lets us regard $n \times n$ quaternionic matrices as certain special $2n \times 2n$ complex matrices.  This in turn lets us define a complex-valued determinant of an $n \times n$ quaternionic matrix, called the **Study determinant**, and also a complex-valued trace.

The $n \times n$ quaternionic matrices for which the Study determinant is 1 form the group $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{H})$.   The Lie algebra of $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{H})$ then consists of $n \times n$ quaternionic matrices for which the complex-valued trace is 0.

The Study determinant is the square of the Dieudonné determinant, as shown here:

- Helmer Aslaksen, [Quaternionic determinants](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.65.877&rep=rep1&type=pdf), *The Mathematical Intelligencer* **18** (1996), 57–65.

But the Dieudonné determinant is nonnegative, so in fact the Study determinant also takes only nonnegative real values, and $\mathrm{SL}(n,\mathbb{H})$ is also the group of quaternionic $n \times n$ matrices with Dieudonné determinant 1.

Comment: Do you agree that the condition on the trace in the Lie algebra is wrong in WP? It would remove a complex-1-dimensional i.e. real-2-dimensional space, and does not even give a Lie algebra. (E.g. for $n=1$, $SL(1, \mathbb H)$ gives the norm-1-quaternions all right, but its Lie algebra should be the pure quaternions, whereas the WP definition would just give the real span of $j, k$, which is not even closed under the Lie bracket.) As you suggest (?), a correct definition has the trace of the full complex matrix $=0$, equivalently $\mathfrak{Re}(Tr(X))=0$ with Wikipedia's notations.

Comment: See my answer for expanded comment on why the trace condition in the Wikipedia article must be mistaken. If you agree, I will edit the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yes, I believe the definition of $\mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb{H})$ in Wikipedia should say $\mathrm{Re}(\mathrm{tr}(X)) = 0$, not $\mathrm{tr}(X) = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

The Lie algebra of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb H)$ is just the full matrix space $M_n(\mathbb H)$ with commutator bracket. Viewed as Lie algebra this way, it's called $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb H)$).

One can show that this is a reductive Lie algebra. Since its centre $\mathfrak z$ is easily seen to be exactly the *real* scalar matrices, i.e. $\mathrm{diag}(a,a, ..., a)$ with $a\in \mathbb R$, its **derived subalgebra**

$$\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb H):= [\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb H), \mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb H)]$$

consists of those matrices where the **real part of the trace is $0$**. (Remember a quaternion $q = a +bi+ cj +dk$ has a real part $\mathfrak{Re}(x) := a$ and a pure quaternion part $bi+cj+dk$).

This has real codimension $1$ in $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb H)$ and corresponds to the Lie group $SL_n(\mathbb H)$ defined as the kernel of the Dieudonné determinant ([1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieudonn%C3%A9_determinant), [2](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Dieudonn%C3%A9+determinant)).

This obviously avoids the problem in Mariano Suárez-Álvarez' answer. For example, the computation  $[ \begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&-i\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}j&0\\0&-j\end{pmatrix}] = \begin{pmatrix}2k&0\\0&2k\end{pmatrix}$ happens without problem in $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\mathbb H)$. (While the commutator of two matrices with trace $0$ need not have trace $0$ necessarily, the commutator of two matrices whose traces have real part $0$ again has trace with real part $0$, and that's all we need.)

This also corresponds to the construction in the Wikipedia article cited in John Baez' answer, but with the correction alluded to in my comment: When we write a matrix $A \in M_n(\mathbb H)$ as matrix
$$\tilde{A}= \pmatrix{X & -\overline{Y}\\Y & \overline{X}} \in M_{2n}(\mathbb C)$$ (with $X, Y \in M_n(\mathbb C)$), then the condition to be in $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb H)$ is **not** $Tr(X) = 0$ as claimed there, but rather $\mathfrak{Re}(Tr(X))=0$ or equivalently $Tr(\tilde{A})=0$.

---

**Note 1**: It's worthwhile to check all this already in the non-trivial basic case $n=1$. We have $\mathrm{GL}_1(\mathbb H) = \mathbb H^*$, $\mathrm{SL}_1(\mathbb H) =$ the norm-1-quaternions ([which is a real Lie group $\simeq SU_2$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Using_quaternions_of_unit_norm)), and $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb H) = \mathbb H$ which splits, stable under commutators, as

$$ \mathbb H  = \underbrace{\mathbb R}_{\text{centre}} \oplus \underbrace{\text{ pure quaternions }}_{\text{real Lie algebra } \simeq \mathfrak{su}_2 (\simeq \mathfrak{so}_3)}$$

And when written as complex matrices $\pmatrix{\alpha & -\bar{\beta}\\\beta& \bar{\alpha}}$, the subspace of pure quaternions is indeed that with $\alpha + \bar\alpha = 0$ or equivalently $\mathfrak{Re}(\alpha)=0$, not just the ones with $\alpha=0$.

---

**Note 2**: All this generalizes in the best way possible to a base field $k$ (to be safe, $char(k)=0$ although much goes through at least if for $char(k)$ does not divide $n$) and a [$k$-central division algebra $D$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_simple_algebra) (of degree $d:= \sqrt{\dim_k D}$ say). Then again one defines the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(D)$ as the derived subalgebra of the full matrix algebra $\mathfrak{gl}_n(D)$, which is of $k$-codimension $1$. It turns out to be an absolutely simple $k$-Lie algebra of type $A_m$, where $m = dn-1$, of $k$-rational rank $n-1$, with Satake-Tits diagram

[image]

For more details, see sections 4.4 and 4.5.2 of [my thesis](https://smf.emath.fr/publications/algebres-de-lie-semi-simples-et-leur-classification-sur-les-corps-p-adiques). (Note the [errata](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/96384/torsten-schoeneberg?tab=profile) for page 93.)

It matches the group case as presented in [Tits, Jacques (1966), "Classification of algebraic semisimple groups", Algebraic Groups and Discontinuous Subgroups (Proc. Sympos. Pure Math., Boulder, Colo., 1965), Providence, R.I.: American Mathematical Society, pp. 33–62](https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/%7Epanchish/ETE%20LAMA%202018-AP/Borel_Algebraic%20Groups%20and%20Discontinuous%20Subgroups.pdf)

[image]

And of course for the Hamilton quaternions, we just have $d=2$ and the above collapses to the second row in [Onishchik / Vinberg's table 4](https://books.google.de/books?id=l8nJCNiIQAAC&pg=PA229&redir_esc=y&hl=de#v=onepage&q&f=true) (they just exclude the compact form $\mathfrak{sl}_1(\mathbb H)$, which in their notation would be $p=0$ and as said above is just $\simeq \mathfrak{su}_2$, with diagram one black dot):

[image]